# Jira - Automatically closing main item when last sub-task is closed

Tags: jira, kanban

I use a Kanban board with a Scrum development project. I've seen that Jira can automatically ask the user whether or not to close the primary item; when the last of its sub-tasks are closed. But this isn't happening with my Kanban board.

What triggers Jira explicitly to ask the user whether to close the main item? Does this need to be configured?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the end, I fixed this by installing an add-on, Adaptavist ScriptRunner for JIRA.

This allows you to create a post function that updates the main item when the status of a sub-task changes.

I wanted to only close the main item when all sub-tasks were closed, not whenever one sub-task is closed. To make that work, I added a condition so the main item can only be closed when all sub-tasks are closed. I could create this condition even without ScriptRunner.

I didn't have to write a script or do any other programming. It was pretty issue once I installed ScriptRunner.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done in the post function. Just create a small script that checks if all of the subtasks are closed, which can then push the parent task in the necessary transition or else you can throw an event when the sub tasks are closed and use the Auto Tranisiotn Listener in JIRA Toolkit to do the transition.